# Is it possible to sample a signal with a sample frequency of 48kHz?

Tags: sensors, esp32

I want to have a filter with a 48kHz sample frequency, is that possible using the esp32?

Here is a part of the code i developed using the arduino IDE:

```
void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500);

  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);

  /*
     The following function allows you to obtain more information
     related to the state of network and IoT Cloud connection and errors
     the higher number the more granular information you’ll get.
     The default is 0 (only errors).
     Maximum is 4
  */
  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
  Pot = (float) analogRead(PinADC_sensor_35) * 3.3 / 4096;
  
  
  
  float t = micros()/1.0e6;
  float xn = sin(2*pi*200*t);
 
  delayMicroseconds(21); 
  //delay(0.020833);


  float H1yn = (1/1)*(H1yn1*(-0.2025) + 0.6*xn + 0*xn1); 
  xn1 =xn;
  H1yn1 = H1yn;

  float H2yn = (1/1)*(H2yn1*(-0.2025) + 1*H1yn + 0.3*xn2 );
  xn2 = H1yn;
  H2yn1 = H2yn;

  float H4yn = (1/1)*(H4yn1*(-0.9097) + 1*H2yn - 1*xn4);
  xn4 = H2yn;

  SinalQuadrado = SinalQuadrado + H4yn*H4yn;
  k++;
```

Does the delayMicroseconds(21) have any effect? I stop the program for 21 mili seconds (48kHz) to sample a signal.

Comment: You need to take into account all the other things going on in the loop as well, not just the delay. Your sampling frequency will probably be nowhere near 48kHz.

Comment: @StarCat How can i certify that i have a sampling frequency of 48kHz?

Comment: @jsotola Perhaps that's a bad computation in my part. But even if i use the delay function with 21milliseconds how can i be assured the signal will be sampled at 48kHz?

Comment: 21us is the correct value for 48kHz, but the rest of your code also takes time to execute. I would guess that the Arduino cloud update is taking significantly longer (since network action mostly takes some time to execute). Probably you need interrupts to do this, though I'm not sure how this works with an ESP32